# Visual C++ 2013 lnk2019 error

Tags: visual-c++

I am just getting started with visual cpp 2013 . I looked around the web for tutorials and tried running the following code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI winMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello World"), _T("A Sample Application"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

It throws the following error

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users......\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)    SampleApp

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here and can someone suggest site for latest tutorials (besides msdn).

Comment: You are missing a definition for `WinMain`. You have a function called `winMain` which is not the same.

Comment: Ok, so i went to msdn and checked out microsofts sample application and saw they used something like this:

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)

So i renamed my winMain to wWinMain and surprise... it compiled without any errors..

So my new questipon is.. is winMain a reserved keyword? I googled it but it only confused me more!

Comment: C is case sensitive. `WinMain` is not the same as `winMain`.

Comment: its wWinMain not simply winMain. I know that it is case sensitive but its a totally different variable name now. I also checked that the compiler throws lnk2019 error for any other name. It is just supposed to be a variable, why can we use any other name?

Comment: There are two entry points for Windows applications. WinMain is for ANSI programs. wWinMain is for Unicode programs. winMain does not match either.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. That was a real noob mistake. BTW should I use wWinMain than for all apps or WinMain still has it uses?

Comment: New applications should use Unicode and wWinMain.

Answer (score 0):

I think Raymond Chen already answered your question, but you don't think so. Let me try it again.

From your code, you misspelled 'wWinMain'. The correct one has 8 characters, yours have only 7 characters. You see, that is the problem.

I tried it in VS 2013: replacing your winMain with wWinMain. Project built and ran without problem. Please, try it again.